# How to keep real values of grouped variable within dplyr package in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

My data is something like this:

```
 group <- c(21, 21, 21, 9, 9, 9, 25, 25, 25)
 a <- c(8,3,5,6,8,3,3,9,3)
 b <- c(4,9,0,1,3,5,6,1,1)
 c <- c(1,7,2,5,6,8,4,8,6)
 value <- c(23,34,43,52,65,21,12,89,76)
 df <- data.frame(group,a,b,c,value)
```

I applied following function to it.

```
 out <- df %>%
   select(group, a, b, value) %>%
   group_by(group = gl(n()/3, 3)) %>%
   summarise(res = mean(value), a=a[1], b=b[1])
 print(out)
```

Then I am getting following result.

```
 group   res     a     b
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1      33.3     8     4
2  2      46       6     1
3  3      59       3     6
>
```

My question is how to keep the orgiignal values of ID as they were in the output df like this

```
 group   res     a     b
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21      33.3     8     4
2   9      46       6     1
3  25      59       3     6
>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are overwriting your `group` variable in `group_by` call hence you are not getting the original variable. You need to use some other name in `group_by` and then do the calculations.

We can use two options -

1) With `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group1 = gl(n()/3, 3)) %>%
  summarise(res = mean(value), a=a[1], b=b[1], group = group[1])

#  group1   res     a     b group
#  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1       33.3     8     4    21
#2 2       46       6     1     9
#3 3       59       3     6    25
```

2) With `mutate`

```
df %>%
  select(group, a, b, value) %>%
  group_by(group1 = gl(n()/3, 3)) %>%
  mutate(res = mean(value), a=a[1], b=b[1]) %>%
  slice(1)
```

In both the case, if you are no longer interested in keeping the grouping variable do `ungroup() %>%  select(-group1)` to remove it.